# How to install eclipse for php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse

I have a web project containing mainly php and javascript files along with some html and css files. Now I would like to use eclipse as my IDE for all of these. But looking at eclipse.org - I'm confused...

There are so many different tools and versions, I really don't know what to do or how to set this up. I found the eclipse PDT for php and there's something called wild web developer which seems to be for js, html and more, but not php.

Is there a package I can download and install that does what I want? Or do I have to configure that myself somehow? If the latter - can anyone point me to tutorial for dummies? It's been 14 years since I used eclipse and it seems I've forgotten everything.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers
The essential tools for any PHP developer, including PHP language support, Git client, Mylyn and editors for JavaScript, TypeScript, HTML, CSS and XML.

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/r/eclipse-ide-php-developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to [eclipse packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/). You can find the distribution for your language.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noticing, that when you upgrade from an older Eclipse for PHP develpers edition and are missing Javascript-Editors entirely, that you can manually install the "Wild Web Editor". It is included in the current Eclipse-PHP_Package but didn't install itself when upgrading (at least in my case).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that as javascript is not really supported by my version even though it's pretty new. And because I once knew someone with the same nickname I have to ask: are you the same chrisman that was active on Taladas.de nearly two decades ago?

Comment: It should be noted that at least during last weeks (2021-W22/2021-W23) it seems that if you install PDT from distribution and then try to update it using Help - Check for Updates ... there'll be updates but after those have installed, your Eclipse installation no longer understands JavaScript.

Comment: @Merion: No, that must have been another Chrisman. Just now saw your comment...